# Немигающий progressBar с возможностью задать текст внутри

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, компоненты

Иногда нужно иметь прогрессбар с текстом внутри, а нейтивный прогрессбар не имеет возможности выдавать текст внутри даного компонента.
Как реализовать?

В интернете всюду решения которые или с рамкой вокруг текста (тупо лейбл на прогрессбар налеплен) или кастомные компоненты, которые банально мигают во время работы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Т.к. всюду встречал только мигающие (blinking/flickering) решения, то решился написать свой собственный компонент -- TextProgressBar и поделится с общественностью.

Соурс код можно найти здесь: https://github.com/ukushu/TextProgressBar

[image]

Примеры:

[image]
[image]
[image: no blinking/flickering TextProgressBar]
[image: no blinking/flickering TextProgressBar]
[image]
[image]

---

Особенности кода, которые нужно иметь ввиду тому, кто решится повторить "подвиг":

Отсутствие мигания кастомного компонента можно достигнуть при помощи кода, оторый отключает "лишние" стили оригинального компонента

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

на стадии инициализации компонента.

---

Так же можно столкнутся с проблемами обновления настроек заданных через VisualStudio. Для того что бы это обойти, нужно вызывать при изменении проблемных property:

```
Invalidate();
```

что бы вижуалка перерисовала заново компонент.

---

И так же не нужно допускать ошибку которую я сначала допустил при написании: не забываем что многие из классов для отрисовки элементов (да и сам контрол) являются дочерними от IDispousable, а, значит, должны вызывать `.Dispose` как только будут не нужны.

---

Для распихивания пропертей по категориям в вижуалке нужно подписывать их следующим образом

```
[Category("Additional Options")]
//обьявление самой проперти
```

---

Все остальное - просто логика отрисовки и реализации вашего кастомного компонента.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87324/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-c-winforms---progressbar--).

Comment: Почему бы для WPF не сделать. Жду ссылку))

Comment: 1. я впф не использую пока что и 2. я еще этот не довел до толка, если чесно) Но уже лучше чем аналоги которые можно нагуглить...

Comment: А то я там нашел один баг странный... Который сложно отрепродьюсить и если получается - то сложно понять в чем причина... Странный, кароч.... Но он только в эдиторе, в готовой программе пашет идеально все.

Comment: @Aqua я запостил еще один ответ, не отдельный компонент, но вполне себе решение для WPF

Answer (score 3):

Так уж вышло что заодно и WPF начал осваивать...
Мало ли, может кому пригодится:

**Value/Maximum**

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar Name="pbUsrLvl"
                 Minimum="1" 
                 Maximum="99" 
                 Value="59" 
                 Margin="5"  
                 Height="24"  Foreground="#FF62FF7F"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}/{1}">
                <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="pbUsrLvl" />
                <Binding Path="Maximum" ElementName="pbUsrLvl" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Результат:

[image]

---

То же самое, но с процентом прогресса:

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar Name="pbLifePassed"
                 Minimum="0" 
                 Value="59" 
                 Maximum="100"
                 Margin="5" Height="24" Foreground="#FF62FF7F"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=pbLifePassed, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Шедевр. Правда, когда писал коммент, ещё не силен был в WPF и сейчас уже умею такое делать, но думаю, другим поможет. Спасибо)